# How do I bind an `DependenyProperty` to another attachable `DependencyProperty`?

Tags: wpf, binding

I want to have a singleton that holds some values **S1** and **S2** that I can bind to. The goal is to have some UIElements update when its value changes. The problem is that I want to use the value inside of a reused `DataTemplate`. That means that I cannot bind directly to a dependency property of the singleton but this has to be set outside.

To correctly pass updates the values have to be `DependencyProperty`. Because I dont know to which property I have to bind I created another attachable property **AttProperty** of the same type as the values. Now I tried to bind the **S1** to **AttProperty** but this gives me an error:

> Additional information: A 'Binding' cannot be set on the
>   'SetAttProperty' property of type 'TextBox'. A 'Binding' can only be
>   set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

**So how can I bind with an attachable `DependencyProperty` to another `DependencyProperty`**?

Here is the code for the singleton I have so far (C#):

```
public class DO : DependencyObject
{
  // Singleton pattern (Expose a single shared instance, prevent creating additional instances)
  public static readonly DO Instance = new DO();
  private DO() { }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty S1Property = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "S1", typeof(string), typeof(DO),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
  public string S1
  {
    get { return (string)GetValue(S1Property); }
    set { SetValue(S1Property, value); }
  }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty AttProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached( 
    "Att", typeof(string), typeof(DO), 
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender) );
  public static void SetAttProperty(DependencyObject depObj, string value)
  {
    depObj.SetValue(AttProperty, value);
  }
  public static string GetAttProperty(DependencyObject depObj)
  {
    return (string)depObj.GetValue(AttProperty);
  }
}
```

Here is the problematic thing (XAML):

```
<TextBox Name="Input" Text="" TextChanged="Input_TextChanged" local:DO.AttProperty="{Binding Source={x:Static local:DO.Instance}, Path=S1}" />
```

**Update**

With the changes of Bojin Li the errors go away. But one issue remains - if I now try to update the singleton with the help of the attached property like this:

```
<TextBox local:DO.Att="{Binding Source={x:Static local:DO.Instance}, Path=S1, Mode=TwoWay}" Text="{Binding Path=(local:DO.Att), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

**Why is the value not propagated to S1 in the singleton?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and wire the changes up to the dependency property changing.

```
public class DO : DependencyObject,INotifyPropertyChanged {
        // Singleton pattern (Expose a single shared instance, prevent creating additional instances) 
        public static readonly DO Instance = new DO();
        private DO() { }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty S1Property = DependencyProperty.Register(
          "S1", typeof(string), typeof(DO),
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,onS1Changed));

        private static void onS1Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
            DO item = d as DO;
            if (item != null) item.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("S1"));
        }

        public string S1 {
            get { return (string)GetValue(S1Property); }
            set { SetValue(S1Property, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty AttProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
          "Att", typeof(string), typeof(DO),
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,onAttChanged));

        private static void onAttChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
            DO item = d as DO;
            if (item != null) item.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Att"));
        }

        public static void SetAttProperty(DependencyObject depObj, string value) {
            depObj.SetValue(AttProperty, value);
        }
        public static string GetAttProperty(DependencyObject depObj) {
            return (string)depObj.GetValue(AttProperty);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
        }
   }
```

Comment: This still doesnt update the singleton in case the value in the TextBox changes. If I understand this correctly Att is not changed but its contained property S1. If I would instead re-set Att with the binding an event would be fired. Or do I have a wrong understanding of the update mechanism?

Comment: In the suggested code `onAttChanged` wants the `DependencyObject` to be a `DO`. But `Att` is not set on the singleton `DO` but attached to other elements - a TextBox in this example. So I guess it will never be carried out sucessfull.

Comment: In this case it shouldn't matter because the dependency update should fire instead.  When you say S1 is not changing, how are you checking.  Are you expecting updates as the text changes (ie user typing) or on loss of focus (which is the default)

Comment: You were right - the update happened when the focus was lost. I expected it to be during typing. +1 for clarifying this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you named your Get/Set Accessors correctly for your attached Property as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx).  Try this instead:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AttProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
      "Att", typeof(string), typeof(DO),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
    public static void SetAtt(DependencyObject depObj, string value)
    {
        depObj.SetValue(AttProperty, value);
    }
    public static string GetAtt(DependencyObject depObj)
    {
        return (string)depObj.GetValue(AttProperty);
    }
```

Example Binding:

```
<TextBlock local:DO.Att="{Binding Source={x:Static local:DO.Instance}, Path=S1}"  Text="{Binding Path=(local:DO.Att),RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

Comment: Thanks Bojin Li - the values are now displayed correctly. If I use the same binding to modify the values they are not updated. I updated the question to reflect this. Any idea why the binding is not updating the singleton?